# Unable to power up Bluetooth dongle

Tags: linux-mint, usb, bluetooth

I'm trying to use bluetooth usb dongle with my Linux Mint laptop, but it's not detected by bluetooth-manager, executing

```
hciconfig hci0 up
```

for bluetooth usb dongle (hci0) results in:

```
Can't init device hci0: Operation not supported (95)
```

while for built-in device (hci1) it works fine. How to troubleshoot that?
Some additional information:
hciconfig:

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:11  ACL MTU: 679:9  SCO MTU: 48:16
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:1148 acl:0 sco:0 events:60 errors:0
    TX bytes:736 acl:0 sco:0 commands:60 errors:0

hci1:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 60:57:18:F4:91:3C  ACL MTU: 1021:5  SCO MTU: 96:6
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:2228 acl:0 sco:0 events:108 errors:0
    TX bytes:4699 acl:0 sco:0 commands:108 errors:0
```

dmesg:

```
[ 5513.107365] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 5513.236766] usb 1-3: string descriptor 0 read error: -75
[ 5513.236772] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001
[ 5513.236775] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 064e:9700 Suyin Corp. Asus Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

rfkill:

```
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
4: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
8: hci1: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
10: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem with the exact same Bluetooth Dongle on my desktop PC. Whenever I do `hciconfig hci0 up` (the Bt dongle is `hci0` in my case), I get `debugfs: File 'dut_mode' in directory 'hci0' already present!` in `dmesg` and the device is still shown as **DOWN** with `hciconfig -a`. Perhaps that file is blocking things? I don't know where to find it as "directory 'hci0'" is quite ambiguous.

Comment: I have exactly the same device (tiny USB BT 5.0 dongle from China, price < 2 USD) and exactly the same problem. This is seems to be related to a bug, respectively a regression, in the Linux kernel. See https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60824. There is no solution yet.